# Not-SO Strange C Behavior

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I was playing around with C,and decided to build my own function of `strlen()`and I did.But through doing so I was shocked to find what `{}` could do. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int mystrlen(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    assert(s[0] !='\0');

    for(i = 0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
    // Placing {} here causes the error to disappear //
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    char hello[] = "hello";
    int len = mystrlen(hello);
    printf("Length = %d\n", len);

    return 0;
   }
```

Running this code yields this error:

```
mystrlen.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

**But after placing** `{}` after the while loop there is no longer an error.Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your semi-colon in the `for()` loop is missing, the `return` is parsed as being the body of the loop.

```
for(i = 0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
return i;
```

is parsed as

```
for(i = 0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
{
  return i;
}
```

This means that after the loop, the function ends without a `return`. Adding an empty statement in the form of braces makes the `for` loop have an empty body, which moves the `return` to outside the loop.

Comment: `This means that after the loop, the function ends without a return.` I do not think so - *going by the code which the OP posted* it guarantees return of `0`. http://ideone.com/gCkrb6

Comment: @al-Khwārizmī: Try passing  `""` to the OP's `strlen()`.

Comment: @alk - The code is static, OP is not taking input from anywhere. I clearly mentioned going by what the OP posted.

Comment: Fair enough ... @al-Khwārizmī

Comment: @al-Khwārizmī Sure, but from a static analysis (what the compiler does) the function is missing a `return`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have a semi-colon missing:

```
for(i = 0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)     ; //<--
```

Comment: Oh, Silly me. Such a mistake!

Comment: @cmaster I actually understand now why. No explanation needed.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent such errors, I write the braces always

```
for(i = 0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
{ /* increment i */ }
```

Also note, that:

```
for ( <expression1> ; <expression2> ; <expression3> ) <statement>
```

is equal to:

```
<expression1>;
while (<expression2>)
{
   <statement>
   <expression3>;
}
```

So to be more explicit, you could also write:

```
i = 0;
while (s[i] !='\0')
{
   i++;
}
```